# Как установить отступ в PHP-FFMpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Я использую библиотеку PHP-FFMpeg library (https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg). Для консоли делаю отступ у видео с разрешением 1920 на 1080 таким образом:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop=960:1080, scale=960:1080,pad=w=960+iw:h=ih:x=960:y=0" output.mp4
```

В php пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open('input.mp4');
$video->filters()->crop(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Point(480, 0, true), new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(960, 1080));
$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\x264('aac'), 'output.mp4');
```

Я получаю видео с кропом и расположением по центру кадра, но не справа (как в случае с консольной командой). Могу ли я переместить output.mp4 или установить корректную точку для отображения видео?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Может кому-нибудь тоже пригодится:

```
$advancedMedia = $ffmpeg->openAdvanced(array('input.mp4'));
$advancedMedia->filters()
    ->custom('[0]', 'crop=960:1080, scale=-1:1080, pad=w=960+iw:h=ih:x=960:y=0', '[vmap]');
$advancedMedia
    ->map(array('[vmap]'), new FFMpeg\Format\Video\x264('aac'), 'output.mp4')
    ->save();
```